# Not able to implemant the relationship between crave and replye django

Tags: python, django

I want to save the reply for the related crave.
If some one posted any crave then reply for that crave should get assigned to to that particular crave. I don't want to create object for reply after saving the crave object in database. for one crave there are many reply. and that reply should get related to the crave to which that reply made.
In following code when i submit a crave it is creating the blank object for reply also. If crave submitted, it should create the object for crave only. Not for reply. And if repy made to that crave then it should get related to that particular crave only. using any relationship. And reply and crave should get display on one single template.

views.py

```
@login_required
def crave_edit(request, id=None):
    instance = get_object_or_404(crave_data, pk=id) if id else None
    crave_made = None
    if instance and instance.person != request.user:
        raise PermissionDenied()

    if request.method=="POST":
        form=CraveDataForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=instance)

        if form.is_valid():
            crave_made = form.save(commit=False)
            crave_made.person = request.user
            crave_made.save()


    else:                    
        form=CraveDataForm(instance=instance)  

    return render(request, "crave/crave.html", {'form' : form,'crave_made':crave_made})


@login_required
def crave_view(request, id):
    #what id is this? this is crave_data id
    crave = get_object_or_404(crave_data, pk=id)
    check = comments.objects.filter(crave=crave.id)
    if request.method=="POST":
        form=CraveReplyForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            reply = form.save(commit=False)
            reply.person=request.user
            reply.crave = crave
            reply.save()                    
    else:                    
        form=CraveReplyForm()  
    print "somehave"
    print id
    print "alasj"
    return render(request, "crave/comment.html", {'crave': crave, 'form' : form, 'check':check})
```

models.py

```
class crave_data(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(User)

    post=models.TextField(blank = True,null = True)
    date= models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.post



class comments(models.Model):

    crave=models.ForeignKey(crave_data, blank = True,null = True)
    reply=models.CharField(max_length=1000, blank = True,null = True)

    date= models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.reply
```

Help me out for this please. Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only the thing you neede is crave_data id,

do changes in crave_edit view

```
crave_made = None
```

and pass crave_made variable to template.

and in tempalte

crave.html

```
{% if crave_made %}
                    <a href="/crave/reply_get/{{ crave_made.id }}">Continue</button>
                {% endif %}
```

Hope this will help you.